# Google Calendar API library from Spring3?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm working on a web service using Spring Framework.

I want to read/write events to Google calendar using OAuth2 and Google Calendar API. I've been looking for a nice library/example which does this, but cannot find a nice one. It's hard to believe that there are none of those because both Spring3 and Google calendar, I believe, are widely used.

Doesn't someone know any example or library which can do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready-to-use integration provided by Spring Social. The most advanced integration for Google API with Spring Social is http://gabiaxel.github.io/spring-social-google-reference/, but it doesn't manage the Calendar part. You can use the spring-social-google connector to retrieve the OAuth info and then use the official Google SDK for the Calendar (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3)